# C# - Find if a specific value has a duplicate in a list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a use case where, given a huge list of strings and one specific string value pulled from a `DataGridView` row containing those same elements in the same order, I need to find if the list contains another identical entry.  All the existing posts I checked just tell you if there are duplicates period.  Here is what I have so far :

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>{-1, originalRow.Index};

int foundIndex = CompleteScancodeList.IndexOf(originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

if (!indexes.Contains(foundIndex))
{
    //Do something
}
```

The `originalRow` variable is a `DataGridViewRow` that is pulled from iterating over every row of a `DataGridView`.  What I'm effectively doing here is saying : if the index of that element in the list is not -1 and not the same index as the row's index (therefore literally the same element).

I initially managed to make it work with a nested loop but it was too slow for my liking.  How can I make this work the way I want where this condition will only evaluate to true if a given string value is present in a string list but at a different index than the original?

This works, kinda...  It only works if the duplicated element is before the original element in the list.  Similarly, if I use the `LastIndexOf` method, it only works if the duplicated element is after.

Comment: Why would you need a nested loop?  Scan the list until you find the second of the value in question or you exhaust the list: one loop.

Comment: Your approach is generally ok, but not effective. Replace `List` with any kind of `ISet`, say, `HashSet<int>` is fine. Then your loop condition will be `if (indexes.Add(foundIndex)) // it is a dupe`.

Comment: I found a neat way of doing it : if (CompleteScancodeList.FindAll(
                entry => entry.Equals(originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString())).Count > 1).  In other words, if the FindAll() method searching for the value in question returns an array bigger than 1 it has a duplicate.  Is that a good approach?

Comment: @Martin OP asked to find particular duplicate item and handle it somehow. At least, I get it this way.

Comment: I am the OP :P.  I would eventually like to handle it yes but for now I just need to know whether a duplicate element exists at a different index

Comment: If you want to tell if there are duplicates, you can check if size of original list matches the size of same list after calling `Distinct()` LINQ extension method.

Comment: You can also do `CompleteScancodeList.Count(entry => entry == originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) > 1`

Comment: @colinD that also works, cleaner too.  It is however still pretty slow.  Can this be sped up somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would say that the recommendation from @Crypt32 of using some kind of `ISet` would make it faster.

Comment: ISet will boost the performance significantly, especially on large sets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from phone, sorry for terrible formatting and typos. So, tell if list have duplicates:

```
if (list.Count != list.Distinct().Count) { // list has dupes }
```

Find particular duplicates and handle them:

```
var set = new HasSet<int>();
foreach (var item in list) {
    if (!set.Add(item)) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

You can replace foreach with for loop if you need actual indexes in array.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
//Search the index of first element
int foundIndex = CompleteScancodeList.IndexOf(originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
//If the index found is row's index
if(foundIndex == originalRow.Index)
    //Search the index of next element
    foundIndex = CompleteScancodeList.IndexOf(originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), originalRow.Index + 1);

//If something is found
if (foundIndex != -1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Other solution with explicit loop :

```
var hasDuplicate = false;
var index = 0;
foreach(var element in CompleteScancodeList)
{
    if(element == originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() && index != originalRow.Index)
    {
        hasDuplicate = true;
        break;
    }
    index++;
}

if (hasDuplicate)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: I thought of this but you end up running IndexOf twice.  On a list of 50 000 items that takes way too long.

Comment: The second index begin where the first stop.

Comment: Down vote because this solution has terrible performance (O(n)^2). It is possible to reduce it to O(n).

Comment: This solution doesn't scan the ENTIRE list twice though.  That would therefore be somewhere between O(n) and O(n)^2 i suppose?

Comment: If only last element in list is duplicated, then you get O(n)^2

Comment: didn't think of that, yeah no go on this one

Comment: It's O(n). The second iteration begin where the first stop (+1 to jump the cell's element).

Comment: you are right, it is O(n).  I will try it and see if it's faster.

Comment: I add a solution with a explicit loop (IndexOf do implicit loop). Maybe the code will be more clear.

Comment: I would go with OP provided solution by cganging List with Set. It is short and fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example how to find the duplicate numbers in a list and store the unique values selected from first list into the second list

```
            List<int> LST = new List<int> { 10, 34, 43, 75, 10, 67, 30, 200, 30, 100, 30 };
        List<int> LST_2 = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < LST.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < LST.Count; j++)
            {
                if (LST[j] == LST[i])
                {

                    if (!LST_2.Contains(LST[i]))
                    {
                        LST_2.Add(LST[i]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var N in LST_2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(N);
        }
```

i wish this help you

Comment: that was precisely my first approach but I'd like to speed it up if possible.

Comment: It always contains it, it contains the same elements as the table.  I need to see if it contains it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the first index of the value you're searching for:

```
string searchedValue = originalRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
int foundIndex = CompleteScancodeList.IndexOf(searchedValue);
```

You can use linq `.Skip()` method to get only the remaining elements. Then use `.Any()`, which will stop executing once the condition is met.

```
CompleteScancodeList.Skip(foundIndex).Any(entry => entry == searchedValue);
```

But it's still iterating twice, once for `IndexOf` and once for `Any`.

Comment: THIS is promising!  Hold on!

Comment: I think all answers here are doing the same, just using linq or explicit loops. I guess it would need to be bench-marked to see what works best.

Comment: This method does not guarantee that the foundIndex returned from IndexOf is the index of my row in the table though, right?